# When does componentWillUnmount actually fire

Tags: reactjs

I was playing the React Lifecycle Methods and i came across a peculiar aspect of `componentWillUnmount`

**Plot: 1**

```
// this.state.test is false by default

render() {
    let test1 = <Test id="1" />
    let test2 = <Test id="2" />
    return this.state.test ? test1 : test2
}
```

The id prop is there just to distinguish between the two elements, Now after the state changes `this.state.test` becomes `true` then `test1` will be rendered and `test2` will be removed, therefore I would expect that `componentWillUnmount` will fire for `test2` which it doesn't for some reason

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sj3hfx6t/)**

---

**Plot: 2**

```
// this.state.test is false by default

render() {
    let test1 = <div><Test id="1"/></div>
    let test2 = <React.Fragment><Test id="2"/></React.Fragment>
    return this.state.test ? test1 : test2
}
```

However when the components are wrapped in different parent elements `componentWillUnmount` fires as expected.

**Doesn't work if both parents are of the same element type (two div tags) also they don't necessarily have to be div and a fragment I tried it with p tag button tag etc.**

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9c03zbwn/)**

---

Questions:

1. Why this is happening?
2. How can I get `componentWillUnmount` to fire without changing the parent?
3. When does `componentWillUnmount` actually fire?
4. Do React components implement the singleton pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does tree diffing by element type and key. In your second example the element type changed from `Test` to `div`. More in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html